java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.signuploginrealtime/com.example.signuploginrealtime.SignupActivity}
I have google-services.json on the App>src. Im trying to use Firebase Auth and Realtime Databse, but I don't know what I'm doing wrong.
I get this error every time, even when I create a new project:

java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.signuploginrealtime/com.example.signuploginrealtime.SignupActivity}

package com.example.signuploginrealtime;

import androidx.annotation.NonNull;
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.text.TextUtils;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;
import com.google.firebase.database.DataSnapshot;
import com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseError;
import com.google.firebase.database.ValueEventListener;
import android.util.Log;
import com.google.firebase.FirebaseApp;
import com.google.firebase.auth.AuthResult;
import com.google.firebase.auth.FirebaseAuth;
import com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseReference;
import com.google.firebase.database.FirebaseDatabase;
import com.google.android.gms.tasks.OnCompleteListener;
import com.google.android.gms.tasks.Task;

public class SignupActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    EditText signupName, signupEmail, signupUsername, signupPassword;
    TextView loginRedirectText;
    Button signupButton;
    FirebaseDatabase database;
    DatabaseReference reference;
    FirebaseAuth mAuth;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_signup);

        // Initialize FirebaseApp
        FirebaseApp.initializeApp(this);

        // Initialize Firebase Authentication
        mAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();

        // Initialize Firebase Database
        database = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance();
        reference = database.getReference("users");

        signupName = findViewById(R.id.signup_name);
        signupEmail = findViewById(R.id.signup_email);
        signupUsername = findViewById(R.id.signup_username);
        signupPassword = findViewById(R.id.signup_password);
        signupButton = findViewById(R.id.signup_button);
        loginRedirectText = findViewById(R.id.loginRedirectText);

        signupButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                String name = signupName.getText().toString().trim();
                String email = signupEmail.getText().toString().trim();
                String username = signupUsername.getText().toString().trim();
                String password = signupPassword.getText().toString().trim();

                if (TextUtils.isEmpty(name)) {
                    signupName.setError("Please enter your name");
                    return;
                }

                if (TextUtils.isEmpty(email)) {
                    signupEmail.setError("Please enter your email");
                    return;
                }

                if (TextUtils.isEmpty(username)) {
                    signupUsername.setError("Please enter a username");
                    return;
                }

                if (TextUtils.isEmpty(password) || password.length() < 8) {
                    signupPassword.setError("Please enter a password with at least 8 characters");
                    return;
                }

                // Check if the username is unique
                reference.child(username).addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                        if (dataSnapshot.exists()) {
                            signupUsername.setError("Username already exists");
                            return;
                        }

                        // Create a new user
                        mAuth.createUserWithEmailAndPassword(email, password)
                                .addOnCompleteListener(SignupActivity.this, new OnCompleteListener<AuthResult>() {
                                    @Override
                                    public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<AuthResult> task) {
                                        if (task.isSuccessful()) {
                                            Toast.makeText(SignupActivity.this, "You have signed up successfully!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                                            Intent intent = new Intent(SignupActivity.this, LoginActivity.class);
                                            startActivity(intent);
                                        } else {
                                            Toast.makeText(SignupActivity.this, "Registration failed. Please try again.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                                            Log.e("SignupActivity", "Registration failed", task.getException());
                                        }
                                    }
                                });
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {
                        Log.e("SignupActivity", "Error checking username uniqueness", databaseError.toException());
                    }
                });
            }
        });
    }
}

I know this error appeared on forum million of times, but please help me find what I missed. Thanks for the help.

signupButton is not initialized before use.  In fact, none of your ui elements are initialized.  Either use findViewById or use view binding.  In general, learn to use logcat to find exception traces such as would occur in this case.

Also this statement does not make sense: Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, MainActivity.class); - it means start the MainActivity from the MainActivity - and given title maybe posted wrong code?

Thanks for the help i posted the right code.

Please edit your question and add the entire error message and indicate which is the exact line of code at which the error occurs. Please respond using @AlexMamo
